# Itunes crashing While launch on Windows PC

Tags: itunes, quicktime

This is a little weird problem I use a windows 8 PC and after a recent upgrade to iTunes it started to fail on launch.

Looked in multiple forums but there is no help available even on apple online forums.

People have mentioned on these forums that Contacting Windows and Apple forums is not helping much as there is no response on this issue.

Of course its disheartening for loyal iTunes user like me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried playing around with itunes in order to find this solution on this issue and i found that there are multiple reasons why this error could occur, There are multiple solutions to this problems:

**Solution-1:** (This Worked for me)

1. Open QuickTime
2. From QuickTime menu Go To "Edit -> Preferences ->
   QuickTime Preferences"
3. Go To audio tab Check if Safe Mode
   (waveout only) is selected.
4. Change this selection to Direct Sound
   instead.
5. Apply changes. Relaunch ITunes.

**Solution-2:** (you loose all iTunes data in this approach)

1.Open iTunes library saved on your local drive in my case: "C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\"
2.Rename the ITunes folder to something else like iTunes old.

3.Relaunch iTunes.

Restoring iTunes Data: Copy and paste iTunes data manually, into newly created iTunes folder (Be selective here while selecting) and Relaunch iTunes.

**Solution-3:** (Read it on one of apple forums credits to actual owner who suggested this intresting fix)

1. Unplug your laptop from internet and ensure you are offline.
2. Launch iTunes [this time it does not crash :)]
3. Open Preferences (iTunes).
4. Go to parental preferences.
5. Enable checkbox iTunes store to disable access to iTunes store.
6. Reconnect & Relaunch to enjoy.

Will include more fixes as and when I am ready with posting of that till then happy ituning.